# how to navigate next, previous, first and last recordset in javascript sqlite database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite

I want to add the functionality of navigating to next, previous, first and last row in sqlite database, also if possible navigate to certain row.here is the code to open a database and retrieve rows. please help. thanks in advance

const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

// open the database
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./mybook.db');
console.error(err.message);

```
console.log("Connected to the mybook database.");


db.serialize(() => {
db.each(`SELECT questions as question,
              wronganswer as wronganser
       FROM beginner`, (err, row) => {
if (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
console.log(row.no + "\t" + row.questions);
});
});

db.close((err) => {
if (err) {
console.error(err.message);
}
 console.log("Close the database connection");
});
```